# Using a FULL JOIN in a SELECT, How can I use certain column from a Table but if it is null use a column from another Table?

Tags: sql, full-outer-join, sql-null

I have two tables:

```
-- Foo --                 -- Bar --
Street | City | Sales     Street | City | Purchases
  X    |  A   |  2           Y   |  B   |   1
  Y    |  B   |  3           Z   |  C   |   4
```

**I have to return this:**

```
Street | City | Profit
  1    |  A   |   2
  2    |  B   |   2
  3    |  C   |  -4
```

The only thing that came to my mind was this:

```
SELECT f.street, f.city, b.street, b.city, ISNULL(f.sales,0) - ISNULL(b.purchases,0) as Profit
FROM Foo f FULL JOIN Bar b
ON f.street = b.street AND f.city = b.city
```

I know this isn't what I need but got this result:

```
Street | City | Street | City | Profit
  1    |  A   |  NULL  | NULL |   2
  2    |  B   |   2    |  B   |   2
 NULL  | NULL |   3    |  C   |  -4
```

How can I combine the columns so when it finds in one table use that one and vice versa?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce()` in the `select` clause:

```
select coalesce(f.street, b.street), coalesce(f.city, b.city)
    coalesce(f.sales, 0) - coalesce(b.purchases, 0) as profit
from foo f 
full join bar b on f.street = b.street and f.city = b.city
```

If your database supports the `using` clause to `joins`, this is simpler:

```
select street, city, 
    coalesce(f.sales,0) - coalesce(b.purchases,0) as profit
from foo f 
full join bar b using(street, city)
```

Comment: i'm getting less lines in the result, shouldn't i get the same amount of lines?

Comment: @PupiSala: this produces the same number of lines as your original query. I only modified the `select` clause.

Comment: I simplified the question, but my real case have multiple lines for the same street-city. And i am using SUM and GROUP BY. And I'm getting more rows in the original query and less with  the one with coalesce

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is `union all` and aggregation:

```
select street, city, sum(sales), sum(purchases),
       sum(sales) - sum(purchases) as profit
from ((select street, city, sales, 0 as purchases
       from foo
      ) union all
      (select street, city, 0, sales
       from bar
      )
     ) fb
group by street, city;
```

This is safer than a `full join` because it will work if there are multiple rows in either table for a `street`/`city` combination.